# UniversalImageLoader blurry image

Tags: android, android-imageview, blur, universal-image-loader

I'm using UniversalImageLoader (https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
I experience the following bug:
I'm using a ListView of ImageView and each ImageView has a different height,
So in the list adapter I'm changing the layout height and width on the BindView method:

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(newWidth,newHeight);
holder.getPostMainPhoto().setLayoutParams(lp);
```

The problem is that occasionally the image become blurry. When I scroll up or down couple of times it goes back to be normal but then again become blurry.

When I use fixed height and width (i.e. I don't change the ImageView layout) the problem do not happen.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Try to call ImageLoader inside `imageView.post(new Runnable() { ... })`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You can write this as an answer instead of a comment so I could mark this as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `ImageLoader` inside of `imageView.post(new Runnable() { ... })`